# how to account for linewidth in drawing lines within a bounding box

Tags: algorithm, grid, drawing

I am drawing a set of evenly spaced horizontal lines within the entirety of a bounding box.

The problem I am having is that the lines (when larger than 1px) get drawn beyond the top and bottom edges of my bounds.  Half on each side of the top and bottom is missing, to be precise.

Here is some pseudo code that attempts a fix for this, but it didn't work.  It *should* describe what I am trying to do:

```
var halfline = linewidth / 2.;
var maxheight = boxsize.height - halfline;
var minheight = halfline;

//draw h lines    
for(i = 0; i < maxlines; i++)
{
    var xloc = 0;
    var xfrac = i / maxlines - 1;
    var yloc = (xfrac * boxsize.height) + minheight;

    move_to(xloc, yloc);
    line_to(boxsize.width, yloc);
}
```

Please keep in mind that the lang is not important here, just the idea of how to offset and scale the lines (that are drawn within the for loop) properly.

Thanks for any tips...  It's safe to assume the following:

1. the line width is in pixels
2. the coordinate system is pixel-based, from (0,0) to (n,n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think this might help:

```
var availablespace = boxsize.height - linewidth;
...
var yloc = (xfrac * availablespace) + minheight;
```

Comment: thanks, and apologies if i was unclear.  let me know what part you would like clarity on...  in the meantime i will try this out and see if works.

Comment: yes, this works.  thanks very much.  i was thinking about the available space incorrectly and always ended up getting the wrong value for the offset of the group of lines.  also note that i updated my question to be more clear.